# Calling api using php curl?

Tags: php, rest, php-curl

I am calling a sms gateway api and below is my code.

```
$otp="1234";
$mobile_number=1234567890;
$username = 123456;
$hash = 1234;
$from = "SENDER";
$message="Your one time password is ".$otp."";

$payload = "username=".$username."&password=".$hash."&to="."91".$mobile_number."&from=".$from."&text=".$message;
$ch = curl_init('https://sms.zestwings.com/smpp.sms?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // This is the result from the API
curl_close($ch);
echo json_encode($result);
return $result;
```

When I hit the url in browser using all the details like username, password,sender, phone number, OTP is sent to my mobile number and when I try using curl method it gives me error message as follows:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in /var/www/html/api/index.php on line 232
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in /var/www/html/api/index.php on line 232
> User account Deactivated

I don't have any index.php page in server only otp.php page is there, Can anyone me suggest me what went wrong.

Comment: _“When I hit the url in browser”_ … then you are likely making a GET request. Now what type of request did you make with your cURL call there? _“I don't have any index.php page”_ - that is apparently not from _your_ system, but the response the API gave you.

Comment: [link](https://sms.zestwings.com/smpp.sms?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&to=91XXXXXXXXXX&from=XXXXXX&text=xxxxx)  this is the url, i tried like this 
    $url='https://sms.zestwings.com/smpp.sms?username=1234567&password=1234&to=911234567890&from=CRDITO&text=Your otp is 1234';
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

Comment: That is hardly readable in comments, please edit your question and include the new code at the end.

Comment: I have  modified my code and it's working, below I have uploaded my answer

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code and it's working now.

```
$mobile_number=1234567890;
$from = "SENDER";
$message=urlencode("Hello");
$url='https://sms.zestwings.com/smpp.sms?username=123456&password=123&to=91'.$mobile_number.'&from='.$from.'&text='.$message.'';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```